# Convert XSD into SQL relational tables

Tags: c#, c++, sql, visual-studio, xsd

Is there something available that could help me convert a XSD into SQL relational tables? The XSD is rather big (in my world anyway) and I could save time and boring typing if something pushed me ahead rather than starting from scratch.

The XSD is [here](http://www.grip.no/kjemikalier/XMLstandardformat/hmsdatablad.xsd) if you want to have a look. It's a standardized/localized format to exchange MSDS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create database tables from XSD files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Altova's [XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/features_database.html) has a feature that will generate SQL DDL Script from an XSD file. XML Spy will cost you some money though.

Interestingly enough, a developer used a really clever trick of using an XSLT translation to create the DDL script from an XSD file. They have outlined it in two parts [here](http://annlewkowicz.blogspot.com/2007/03/create-ddl-from-dataset-xsd-file.html) and [here](http://annlewkowicz.blogspot.com/2008/01/create-ddl-from-xsd-file-part-ii.html).

I might have to try this out myself for future use...

EDIT: Just found this question asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)...

Answer (score 1):

There is a command-line tool called [XSD2DB](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/), that generates database from xsd-files, available at sourceforge.

For more info: please refer to this existing question [How can I create database tables from XSD files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XSLT transform. See, for example, here: [Generating SQL from XSD and XSL stylesheets with XSLT](http://www.academia.edu/661966/Generating_SQL_schema_XSL_stylesheets_and_XQuery_for_processing_XML_data_based_on_XML_Schema_model_2006_).

Microsoft has a command-line tool for performing XSLT transformations: [Microsoft Command-Line tool for XSLT](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714).

It is also easy to integrate the transforms into a build process using MSBuild or Grunt.

Here is the reference for the Microsoft documentation: [XML Standards Reference, including XSD, XSLT, etc.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256177(v=vs.110).aspx)