# Read xsd schema using c#

Tags: c#, parsing, xsd

We would like to read information out of an xsd file in order to create a table with the same structure.

Is the way to do it just opening the file as an xml file, then parsing it, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This question about creating a SQL Table from XSD was already asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403420/convert-xsd-into-sql-relational-tables and here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files

Comment: @Oded, we are planning on using a sharepoint list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlSchema.Read Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read.aspx