# XPDL XSD to MySQL DDL

Tags: mysql, xml, xsd, ddl

I want to convert this schema

http://wfmc.org/standards/bpmnxpdl_31.xsd

to MySQL DDL statements. Unfortunately, i don't have much time to do this.

What would be the quickest and easiest way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No perfect solution for this. XMLSpy comes close but there is no fully automated way to convert XSD to DDL.

Answer (score 0):

A [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403420/convert-xsd-into-sql-relational-tables) already address this.

The problem is (may be) that an Xml Schema can represent structures that are not easily translated to a relational model in an automated way.

However, [Altova Xml Spy](http://www.altova.com/features_database.html) will try to.

There's an [XSLT](http://www.annlewkowicz.com/2008/01/create-ddl-from-xsd-file-part-ii.html) that will try as well.

I have not used either and therefore cannot comment on how well they may or may not work.

Comment: The XSLT works only with DataSet schema. Exploring XMLSpy now. Looks like its not free.