# Import a schema (via .XSD file) to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, xsd, schema

I have exported MS Access tables as .XSD files and want to import them into MySQL is this possible to do directly or do I have to redefine all of this information in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11805086/5065008). It details the import of the XML and XSD into excel, where you'll want to save it as CSV.

You can then bulk load this CSV into a MySQL database. DB management tools such as Navicat tend to have Import features that make this a trivial process.