# Parse xml with one to many relationship in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have a lot of xml files (and xsd file for them) and a need to save their content parsed in Oracle tables. The xml files have one-to-many relationship.

Here's an example of such file:

```
<Customer>
    <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <Address>
        <City>NY</City>
        <Street>1st Avenue</Street>
    </Address>
    <Address>
        <City>NY</City>
        <Street>2st Avenue</Street>
    </Address>
    <Phone>123456</Phone>
    <Phone>345</Phone>
    <Phone>768567</Phone>
    <Phone>345345</Phone>
</Customer>
```

The real files are around 1000 lines long each, the example is simplified. How do I parse these files in oracle without writing much code? Tables are not created yet so I would like also to know how to create them based on xsd.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of thoughts on this in these past questions:

[How can I create database tables from XSD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)

[Convert XSD into SQL relational tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403420/convert-xsd-into-sql-relational-tables)

Although [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) is not free, you can get a fully-functional 30-day trial for free at [altova.com/download-trial](http://www.altova.com/download-trial.html)