# Create Sql Database using xml schema and xml data file

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd, sql-server-2012-datatools

How to create Database in `Sql Server` using `xml schema` and `xml data` file.

I tried different things I cant solve the problem.

I am using these files

**XML SCHEMA:**
http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd

**XML DATA FILE:** http://www.drugbank.ca/system/downloads/current/drugbank.xml.zip

I tried [How to build a database from an XSD schema and import XML data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628327/how-to-build-a-database-from-an-xsd-schema-and-import-xml-data) but it gives me some errors.  please help me to solve this :)

Comment: Nobody can help you. You haven't told us what's wrong!

Comment: @JohnSaunders when i try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628327/how-to-build-a-database-from-an-xsd-schema-and-import-xml-data. it just give me this error.
"Package Execution completed with error..... "

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using XML and XSD to create a populated database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531266/using-xml-and-xsd-to-create-a-populated-database)

Answer (score -1):

I used to create a array from the xml file and then insert in to the database.