# Visual Studio Dataset to a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, dataset

I have a C# project in Visual Studio with a SQL Server database.
I have a problem with my PC and I lost the database and I don't have a backup or a script to recreate the database and this is medium large.

My question: is there a way to pass the dataset of my project to tables in SQL Server in an automatic way using some tool?

I ever heard that you could create databases from Visual Studio with Entity Framework, but I don't really know how it works.

Here's a screenshot of the dataset:

[image: tables]

[image: file]

Comment: You can certainly re-create the SQL scripts needed to create those tables, from your dataset - and once you do: **STORE THE SCRIPTS** in source control somewhere!

Comment: DataSet itself is not a tool for restoring the database, it is a data container for operating and managing data in a C# project. Typically, a DataSet is used to store and process data retrieved from a database.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is duplicate of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572455/create-sql-server-db-from-dataset). The accepted answer provides a link to a tool that allows you to generate the database from the xsd file.