# Turn an XML file into an MS SQL Server DB

Tags: .net, sql, xml, visual-studio

There are lots of lovely things Visual Studio can do that I don't know about. There is one thing I'm looking for that it may or may not be able to do.

I'm being passed an XML file and I need to display it as a web form. I'll probably build this in ASP.NET MVC because it'll make it quick and simple to do the CRUD operations. I need to add some persistence so I should really convert the schema of the xml file into a single or multiple tables in a SQL Server database.

Not that doing this manually is a problem, but is there a tool or technology I'm unaware of that will help with something like this?

Answer (score 2):

As a first step [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.100).aspx) will create the XSD.

[XSD2DB](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/): See [How can I create database tables from XSD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLXMLBulkLoad for this see
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005