# Importing an XSD file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, xsd

I wish to import my .xsd file into my MySQL database as a schema so i can then put valuesfrom an XML file into the database.

Is there a tool currently available to do this? i'm aware of some closed-sourced tools that can do this and offer a 30-day trail (such as 'Navicat') but i am looking for an open-source project that i can use for a longer period and for free.

Anyone know of such beast?

Comment: found a simular question on here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files

this was 2 years ago, is it the same today?

Answer (score -1):

Check [Hyperjaxb](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home).

Comment: I can't even tell how this relates to xml, please expand your answer.