# XSD to MySQL Schema

Tags: mysql, xml, xsd, rdbms

I need to convert an XML to a MySQL DB Schema.
I have been able to generate the XSD from the XML. Now i want to use the XSD to generate the DB schema in MySQL or PostgreSQL. Can anyone tell me how can i do this or point to any tools which i can use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command-line tool called **[XSD2DB](http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/)**, that generates database from xsd-files, available at sourceforge.

For more info: please refer to this existing question **[How can I create database tables from XSD files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files)**

Comment: Unfortunately it still sopports only SQL Server. And require Windows OS !